# Robot framework: comparing if a list value is on another list

Tags: robotframework

I am generating random strings seen in list 1 and I seeing  to dB via UI. List2 is the query results from the corresponding table. I want to make sure if the values of List 1 is a present in the List 2

${Masterlist} values is [('SVAARtBKECJILJP', None, 'ONFSxMKP', None, 'xFRFAWNI', 'JOxTVMNW')]

${childlist} value is ['xFRFAWNI', 'JOxTVMNW', 'SVAARtBKECJILJP', 'ONFSxMKP']

list should contain sub list ${master} ${randomlist}

Test result : Following values were not found from first list: xFRFAWNI, JOxTVMNW, SVAARtBKECJILJP, ONFSxMKP
Any help will be appreciated!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Show what have you tried; a generalized answer is to loop one of the lists, and see the current element is in the other.

Comment: @Todor                                                                                
${Masterlist} values is   [('SVAARtBKECJILJP', None, 'ONFSxMKP', None, 'xFRFAWNI', 'JOxTVMNW')]

${childlist} value is   ['xFRFAWNI', 'JOxTVMNW', 'SVAARtBKECJILJP', 'ONFSxMKP']




list should contain sub list        ${master}    ${randomlist}


Test result : 

Following values were not found from first list: xFRFAWNI, JOxTVMNW, SVAARtBKECJILJP, ONFSxMKP

Comment: Can you copy the code example to the question, through [edit] functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ${Masterlist} contains a single tuple.

You could try:
List Should Contain Sub List ${MasterList[0]}  ${childlist}

In your example, the values that you are attempting to access are contained in a tuple, which is inside a list.

```
  [ # Start of a list
      ( # Start of a tuple
        'SVAARtBKECJILJP',
         None,
         'ONFSxMKP',
         None,
         'xFRFAWNI',
         'JOxTVMNW'
      )
```

To properly verify ${Masterlist} contains ${childlist}, you will need to reference the values within the tuple, rather than the list.

```
Should Be True    Evaluate    ${Masterlist[0]} == ('SVAARtBKECJILJP', None, 'ONFSxMKP', None, 'xFRFAWNI', 'JOxTVMNW')
```

If ${Masterlist} contains multiple tuples, you can flatten them using some python magic, via the Evaluate keyword:

```
# Say ${Masterlist} equals [('some', 'thing'), ('another', 'thing')]
${Masterlist}    Evaluate    [item for tup in $Masterlist for item in tup]
Should Be True    Evaluate    ${Masterlist} == ['some', 'thing', 'another', 'thing']
```

For more information on flattening tuples within lists check out [this thread that I stole the snippet from](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Granted, this kind of logic is usually better off in a library keyword.

Comment: What if the master list has more than a tuple?